# How to avoid datatype mismatch within pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which can be generated from code below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :['13423523234527afefc9586e8cec5ae2e5c5d46aedcbe6a5652fa0615e92c3ee84bc32792826','123253252364334527afefc9586e8cec536ae2e5c5d46aedcbe6a5652fa0615e92c3ee84bc32792826','123443643643527afefc9586e8cec5346ae2e5c5d46aedcbe6a5652fa0615e92c3ee84bc32792826','1234523463434312de3c1a186a623642a6699bb2f5ab570c37985ec13ed33582486b51aa1234567','123452312de3c1a186a622a6693469bb2f5ab570c37985ec13ed33554321b51aa8891808','1234523146363462de3c1a186a622a3466699bb2f5ab570c37985ec13ed331234551aa8891808','123452312de3c143643a186a622a6699634bb2f5ab570c37985ec13ed12345676b51aa8891808',np.nan,2],'level_1': ['L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L2FR','L2Date','L2value'], 'val3':['Fasting','11/4/2005',1.33,'Random','18/1/2007',4.63,'Fasting','18/1/2017',8.63]})
```

It looks like as shown below

I would like to extract numeric portion (only 9 digits) from the `person_id` column. For which I tried the below

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df.person_id.apply(lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(x)))))
```

In the above code if I don't use **`str(x)`**, it throws an error because elements `0`(`7th row after filling na`) and `2`(`8th row`) are of `integer` type

How can the datatype of elements be different from datatype of the column. I have shown below as well

[image]

How can I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.findall`:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['person_id'] = df['person_id'].astype(str)
df['extracted'] = df['person_id'].str.findall('\d+').apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)[:9])
print(df['extracted'])
```

Output:

```
0    123452795
1    123452795
2    123452795
3    123452312
4    123452312
5    123452312
6    123452312
7            0
8            2
Name: extracted, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there any reason why column datatype and element datatype is different?

Comment: The mixed series of different datatype is also stored using `object` type, if that's what you are asking. Perhaps [`pandas.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes) can provide you better insight :)

Comment: In addition, can I also know why do you have to use `.str` before `findall` because we have already converted the column to `str` type using `df['person_id'].astype(str)`

Comment: By default, it is already being made as column of `str` datatype but wondering why do we need another `.str`

Comment: `.str` doesn't make a column `str`. Rather, it is a special accessor that can only work on column type of `O`. In addition, since `O` dtype `series` can still contain non-strs, `pd.Series.str.*` methods will fail on non-strs and result `NaN`. `astype(str)` is therefore to avoid such cases, making `1` into `'1'`. You can check `pd.Series(['a', 0, 1]).str[0]` vs `pd.Series(['a', 0, 1]).astype(str).str[0]`

Comment: Unable to upvote the comment again as I deselected it by mistake

Comment: @SSMK Hope I've clarified your doubts :)

Comment: Yes, I upvoted your answer and marked as solution. However, I am not able to upvote the comment though it is useful.